# Getting AT&T DSL. Do I have to get one of their "compatible" DSL modems?

Tags: dsl-modem

I want to get the cheap 12 month 6 Mbps DSL deal from AT&T.  I don't yet have a DSL modem or wireless router, so I'd like to buy one on my own and avoid the AT&T pricing on those things.  Their online chat representative pointed me to this list of compatible modems:

https://www.fastaccess.com/content/consumer/popups/modems_popup.html

This is a pretty small list.  Do I have to go with one of these, or is it possible/likely to get another type to work?

Comment: Can you still get the deal if you don't use their equipment?

Comment: You might want to investigate what their policy is if they can't deliver an actual 6Mbps connection.  DSL is kind of hit and miss.  Verizon promised me 3 mbps but after installation wouldn't guarantee even 0.75 mbps over my admittedly aged copper.  Luckily I was on a 30 day trial period and had not committed to pay so I kept my broadband.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't get recommended hardware, good luck getting **ANY** support if/when issues arise.  I have unfortunately had to deal with a large number of ISP reps in a professional capacity (for my customers at the last job), and they are generally clueless.  They have a very strict script they need to follow (reset modem, reset router, etc).

Their logic is designed so that if there is ANY non-standard hardware or software in the system, that **must** be the issue unless you can conclusively demonstrate otherwise.  If you have a self-installed router, or self-installed modem, you will have a lot of hoops to jump through when your connection dies.

Technically other modems should work as well, but be prepared for a hassle if you get one.